# SQL Trigger To Update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Good day I have an external Program that stores information in SQL, I am trying to do a trigger that Updates a table when some of the fields in that Table change.

So I have one column `Contractual Amount` that should be updated everytime any of the values in `ufAPCHANG1EAMNT`, `ufAPHANGE2AMNT` and `ufAPCHANGE3AMNT` changes.

A person can change one or all of these values and can be either +ve or -ve then if they are any changes to those fields the `Contractual Amount` should be updated accordingly but adding the +ve amount and subtracting the negative amount.

Please can you check my code and let me know where I am going wrong.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[trgContractualAmt] 
ON [dbo].[Vendor]
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
    declare 
        @IdI integer,
        @value1 decimal,
        @Value2 decimal,
        @value3 decimal,
        @sum decimal,
        @total decimal

    SELECT 
        @IdI = i.DCLink,
        @value1 = i.ufAPCHANGE1AMT,
        @Value2 = i.ufAPCHANGE2AMNT,
        @value3 =i.ufAPCHANGE3AMNT,
        @total = i.ufAPContAmt
    FROM 
        inserted i
BEGIN
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
        RETURN

    IF @value1 <> (select ufAPCHANGE1AMT from Vendor where DCLink = @IdI)
            UPDATE Vendor
            SET ufAPContAmt = ufAPContAmt + @value1
            where DCLink = @IdI

        if @Value2 <> (select ufAPCHANGE2AMNT from Vendor where DCLink = @IdI)
            UPDATE Vendor
            SET ufAPContAmt = ufAPContAmt + @value2
            where DCLink = @IdI

        if @Value3 <> (select ufAPCHANGE3AMNT from Vendor where DCLink = @IdI)
            UPDATE Vendor
            SET ufAPContAmt = ufAPContAmt + @value3
            where DCLink = @IdI         
END
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT ..... FROM Inserted` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Thank you @marc_s but if you check this is when Updating that particular row, my inserted has only one row.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL.

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking the deleted against the inserted to see if the values change? You shouldn't need to declare variables in this either. Just do the compare.

Comment: Thank you @WEI_DBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest to use simple query when possible:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trgContractualAmt ON dbo.Vendor
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE
            V
        SET
            ufAPContAmt += CASE WHEN (V.ufAPCHANGE1AMT <> I.ufAPCHANGE1AMT)
                                THEN I.ufAPCHANGE1AMT
                                ELSE 0
                           END
            + CASE WHEN (V.ufAPCHANGE2AMNT <> I.ufAPCHANGE2AMNT)
                   THEN I.ufAPCHANGE2AMNT
                   ELSE 0
              END
            + CASE WHEN (V.ufAPCHANGE3AMNT <> I.ufAPCHANGE3AMNT)
                   THEN I.ufAPCHANGE3AMNT
                   ELSE 0
              END
        FROM
            Vendor V
        INNER JOIN inserted I
            ON V.DCLink = I.DCLink;

    END;
```

Comment: Do you really need the Where condition, please check

Comment: Sorry It was a left over from Gerald's code. Ive edited my answer to remove. 
thank you